# Issue with making word bold php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Ok so I have a string that  outputs some text.

> *~ Terraces 
>
>   The apartment has two large terraces. Main terrace (30m2) is accessible from the living room, is fitted with a large wooden table with 6 armchairs and large comfortable wooden sunbeds. The views from here are amazing, you can admire incredible sea views but also you have a fascinating view of La Concha, the striking mountain that sits behind Marbella. Second terrace (14m2) is accessible from the kitchen.*

The only thing I want to do is to make a pattern like this *~ string* to be transformed into **string**.More specifically to get rid of ~, the space and make the text bold.

I created this function:

```
function bold($var) {
$var = preg_replace('/~\s(.*?)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $var);
return $var;
}
```

The function removes the ~ but doesn't make the text bold.Why?Even more oddly, if I insert something between the strong tags I will get that text in bold followed by the text which I want unbolded even though they're in the same tags.

Just as a quick note...$var is in entire string like the one in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need this:

```
$var = preg_replace('/~\s*(\S+)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $var);
```

Comment: +1 for understanding what OP needs and giving him correct answer .

Comment: This works like a charm.Many thanks!!Though now I'm in a puzzle.What is wrong with my function.

Comment: @marianstefi20: `.*?` doesn't make sense unless it is followed by something like `.*?\s` So in your case it was matching 0 length text since your regex is non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. PHP is a server side language, so to make it bold you would probably want to echo back HTML with bold tags.

After you run your regex, why not just do this:

`$var = '<strong>$var</strong>';`

Rather than try and do it all via regular expression?

Comment: I thought at this too but this approach will 'boldify' my entire string.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought that's what you wanted.